# C realpath function doesn't work for strings defined in the source file

Tags: c, linux, realpath

I'm having a weird problem with the `realpath` function. The function works when it is given a string received as an argument for the program, but fails when given a string that I define in the source code. Here is a simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char* fullpath = (char*)malloc(PATH_MAX);
    if(realpath(argv[1], fullpath) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", fullpath);
    }
}
```

When I run this with an argument `~/Desktop/file` (`file` exists and is a regular file) I get the expected output

```
/home/<username>/Desktop/file
```

Here is another version of the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    const char* path = "~/Desktop/file";

    char* fullpath = (char*)malloc(PATH_MAX);
    if(realpath(path, fullpath) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", fullpath);
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get the output

```
Failed
```

Why does the second one fails?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why do you allocate `fullpath` dynamically? Why not an array?

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried printing out `argv[1]` to see what it is? And checking `errno` when the call fails? I also suggest you read [the `realpath` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const char* path = "~/Desktop/file";
```

the *tilde character* (i.e.: `~`) is not being *expanded* (e.i.: replaced with the path of your *home directory*) in your program.

When you provide it as an argument in the command line as in your first program, it is **expanded by the shell**.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is expanding the ~ to the correct name before you run the program and that's what is in argv[1].

When hardcoded, it obviously is not autoexpanding the name for you.